# Gmail authorized application log

Tags: gmail, security

Is there a way to see what exactly any authorized app did (i.e. if it sent/deleted any emails I would like to know this)

Comment: I don't believe there is. Any sent messages should be in your "Sent" label, however, and if messages were deleted they'd be in your "Trash".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, as @ale stated, there is no way to review the activity of authorized apps from your Google account. You would have to check the logs for any apps that those authorized apps accessed -- for example, Gmail's sent items or posts made to a social media site.

The only actions you can take regarding an authorized app are to view specific details about it (name, date access was granted, and which permissions it has) and to revoke access. All of this can be done on [your Google permissions page](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions).

Comment: If you're interested in what Google knows _you've_ been doing, go to https://myactivity.google.com.